# How to convert "camelCase" to "Camel Case"?

Tags: javascript, regex

I’ve been trying to get a JavaScript regex command to turn something like `"thisString"` into `"This String"` but the closest I’ve gotten is replacing a letter, resulting in something like `"Thi String"` or `"This tring"`. Any ideas?

To clarify I can handle the simplicity of capitalizing a letter, I’m just not as strong with RegEx, and splitting `"somethingLikeThis"` into `"something Like This"` is where I’m having trouble.

Comment: How is this a duplicate of that. All that does is capitalize the first character in a string, nothing close to what I want to do.

Comment: Hmm its not a dupe of the question, but the result might be the same.  Or is that not what you wanted to do ?  Elaborate more ?

Comment: For regex practice I suggest RegExr or Expresso to test in and just look at all the regex questions on SO and try to answer them. Regexs are not the simplest thing in the world, but just remember that if your regex is confusing YOU then split it up and work in pieces.

Answer (score 475, accepted):

```
"thisStringIsGood"
    // insert a space before all caps
    .replace(/([A-Z])/g, ' $1')
    // uppercase the first character
    .replace(/^./, function(str){ return str.toUpperCase(); })
```

displays

```
This String Is Good
```

```js
(function() {

  const textbox = document.querySelector('#textbox')
  const result = document.querySelector('#result')
  function split() {
      result.innerText = textbox.value
        // insert a space before all caps
        .replace(/([A-Z])/g, ' $1')
        // uppercase the first character
        .replace(/^./, (str) => str.toUpperCase())
    };

  textbox.addEventListener('input', split);
  split();
}());
```

```css
#result {
  margin-top: 1em;
  padding: .5em;
  background: #eee;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Text to split
  <input id="textbox" value="thisStringIsGood" />
</div>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Good man, splitting it up. Just remember Bobince's advice : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Are you sure this is compatible with IE?  Just tried in IETester7 & got an error.

Comment: Not tested in IE but I see no reason why it should not work :-/

Comment: To add onto this answer, if your string has numbers in it you can add `.replace(/([a-z])(?=[0-9])/g, '$1 ')` to format them correctly

Comment: Also adding: if you have an all caps acronym that you want to keep together you can change the first regex to "/([A-Z][a-z])/"

Comment: "This" -> " This" (unwanted prefix space). Maybe change it to: str.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1).replace(/([A-Z])/g, ' $1')

Comment: I need help on a specific case. How do make 'userID' into 'User ID'? The current solution will result to 'User I D'. And currently I just added `.replace('I D', 'ID')` to solve the problem. But how do I do it dynamically where it would check first if the upper case is not preceded by another upper case before adding a space before it?

Comment: @ColdCerberus You can use: `str.replace(/((?<!^)[A-Z](?![A-Z]))(?=\S)/g, ' $1').replace(/^./, s => s.toUpperCase() );` It will convert `userID` to `User ID`, and it will even convert `userIDField` to `User ID Field`

Comment: Apparently, it results to "UserID Field"

Answer (score 99):

I had an idle interest in this, particularly in handling sequences of capitals, such as in xmlHTTPRequest. The listed functions would produce "Xml H T T P Request" or "Xml HTTPRequest", mine produces "Xml HTTP Request".

```
function unCamelCase (str){
    return str
        // insert a space between lower & upper
        .replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1 $2')
        // space before last upper in a sequence followed by lower
        .replace(/\b([A-Z]+)([A-Z])([a-z])/, '$1 $2$3')
        // uppercase the first character
        .replace(/^./, function(str){ return str.toUpperCase(); })
}
```

There's also a String.prototype version [in a gist](https://gist.github.com/1005915).

Comment: The same can be achieved with 2 replace calls: `str.replace(/((?<!^)[A-Z](?![A-Z]))(?=\S)/g, ' $1').replace(/^./, s => s.toUpperCase() )`

Answer (score 28):

This can be concisely done with regex lookahead ([live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7rpLz/)):

```
function splitCamelCaseToString(s) {
    return s.split(/(?=[A-Z])/).join(' ');
}
```

(I thought that the `g` (global) flag was necessary, but oddly enough, it isn't in this particular case.)

Using lookahead with `split` ensures that the matched capital letter is not consumed and avoids dealing with a leading space if UpperCamelCase is something you need to deal with. To capitalize the first letter of each, you can use:

```
function splitCamelCaseToString(s) {
    return s.split(/(?=[A-Z])/).map(function(p) {
        return p.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + p.slice(1);
    }).join(' ');
}
```

The `map` array method is an ES5 feature, but you can still use it in older browsers with [some code from MDC](http://jsfiddle.net/7rpLz/). Alternatively, you can iterate over the array elements using a `for` loop.

Comment: First function splits it, but does not PascalCase the First word.
Second function fails on a none camelCased case. (e.g: 'id')

Answer (score 22):

I think this should be able to handle consecutive uppercase characters as well as simple camelCase.

For example: someVariable => someVariable, but ABCCode != A B C Code.

The below regex works on your example but also the common example of representing abbreviations in camcelCase.

```
"somethingLikeThis"
    .replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1 $2')
    .replace(/([A-Z])([a-z])/g, ' $1$2')
    .replace(/\ +/g, ' ') => "something Like This"

"someVariableWithABCCode"
    .replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1 $2')
    .replace(/([A-Z])([a-z])/g, ' $1$2')
    .replace(/\ +/g, ' ') => "some Variable With ABC Code"
```

You could also adjust as above to capitalize the first character.

Answer (score 20):

[Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#startCase) handles this nicely with `_.startCase()`

Answer (score 14):

```
function spacecamel(s){
    return s.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1 $2');
}
```

spacecamel('somethingLikeThis')

// returned value: something Like This

Comment: Nice one! this is exactly what i needed i wanted to split eg: DiscoveryChannel and HBO other answers gave me Discovery Channel and H B O, but your answer did the trick for me as HBO stayed intact thank you!

Comment: I always love one line solutions like these

Answer (score 7):

A solution that handles numbers as well:

```
function capSplit(str){
   return str.replace(
      /(^[a-z]+)|[0-9]+|[A-Z][a-z]+|[A-Z]+(?=[A-Z][a-z]|[0-9])/g,
      function(match, first){
          if (first) match = match[0].toUpperCase() + match.substr(1);
          return match + ' ';
          }
       )
   }
```

[Tested here [JSFiddle, no library.](http://jsfiddle.net/xh3HT/) Not tried IE]; should be pretty stable.

Comment: Only one in a long list which correctly handles numbers: "BrochureUSA1999"  to "Brochure USA 1999".

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution here -

```
var value = "myCamelCaseText";
var newStr = '';
for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
  if (value.charAt(i) === value.charAt(i).toUpperCase()) {
    newStr = newStr + ' ' + value.charAt(i)
  } else {
    (i == 0) ? (newStr += value.charAt(i).toUpperCase()) : (newStr += value.charAt(i));
  }
}
return newStr;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about older browsers (or don't mind using a fallback **reduce** function for them), this can split even strings like 'xmlHTTPRequest' (but certainly the likes of 'XMLHTTPRequest' cannot).

```
function splitCamelCase(str) {
        return str.split(/(?=[A-Z])/)
                  .reduce(function(p, c, i) {
                    if (c.length === 1) {
                        if (i === 0) {
                            p.push(c);
                        } else {
                            var last = p.pop(), ending = last.slice(-1);
                            if (ending === ending.toLowerCase()) {
                                p.push(last);
                                p.push(c);
                            } else {
                                p.push(last + c);
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        p.push(c.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + c.slice(1));
                    }
                    return p;
                  }, [])
                  .join(' ');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My version

```
function camelToSpace (txt) {
  return txt
    .replace(/([^A-Z]*)([A-Z]*)([A-Z])([^A-Z]*)/g, '$1 $2 $3$4')
    .replace(/ +/g, ' ')
}
camelToSpace("camelToSpaceWithTLAStuff") //=> "camel To Space With TLA Stuff"
```

Comment: I applied this function in loop on 3000 lines, and got those spaces in front of every line that starts with capital

Answer (score 0):

```
const value = 'camelCase';
const map = {};
let index = 0;
map[index] = [];
for (let i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
  if (i !== 0 && value[i] === value[i].toUpperCase()) {
    index = i;
    map[index] = [];
  }
  if (i === 0) {
    map[index].push(value[i].toUpperCase());
  } else {
    map[index].push(value[i]);
  }
}
let resultArray = [];
Object.keys(map).map(function (key, index) {
  resultArray = [...resultArray, ' ', ...map[key]];
  return resultArray;
});
console.log(resultArray.join(''));
```

Answer (score -7):

Not regex, but useful to know plain and old techniques like this:

```
var origString = "thisString";
var newString = origString.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + origString.substring(1);
```

Comment: no, the question is "thisString" to "This String" ( with a space ) not "ThisString"

Comment: @rob How do you put a space between "this" and "String"?