# Insert space before capital letters

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string, replace

I have a string `"MySites"`. I want to place a space between `My` and `Sites`.

How can I do this in jQuery or JavaScript?

Comment: Can you provide some more detail?  What is the general form of the strings you want to separate?  If it's only that one string, why not just put the space in manually?

Comment: Please be more precise, I don't think anyone can understand what you're asking

Comment: define the pattern that it should match, e.g. "a space when it find 'My' in the string" or "add a space before each capital character, unless it is the first character", or....

Comment: "between MySites".  How can you place a space between 1 thing?  I assume you want "My Sites" as an output.

Answer (score 271, accepted):

You can just add a space before every uppercase character and trim off the leading and trailing spaces

```
s = s.replace(/([A-Z])/g, ' $1').trim()
```

Comment: This also works for "1AndAbove". The other solution does not. Thanks!!

Comment: It "fails" for acronyms, how could we prevent for it to act when 2 or more consecutive caps?

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet easy, modify the regex like this: `/([A-Z]+)/g`. The + will make sure you match as many consecutive capital letters as possible.

Comment: Why is parentheses that you use to surround '[A-Z]' needed in this code?

Comment: @Kristina The parenthesis say 'I am a variable'. Without the parenthesis, it yields the answer '$1y $1ites' for 'MySites'

Answer (score 149):

This will find each occurrence of a lower case character followed by an upper case character, and insert a space between them:

```
s = s.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1 $2');
```

For special cases when 2 consecutive capital letters occur (Eg: ThisIsATest) add additional code below:

```
 s = s.replace(/([A-Z])([A-Z])/g, '$1 $2');
```

Comment: Just a warning, this fails for single letters "ThisIsATest" will result "This Is ATest".

Comment: @Ceres: Good point. That case could be handled by instead inserting a space before any capital that is not the first character, but you still have cases that can't be handled without word recognition, like `"RunThisSQLQuery"`.

Comment: for the "ThisIsATest"  --(not counting the 'RunThisSQLQuery') you could do this:    

str.replace(/([A-Z])/g, ' $1').trim()

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks!

Answer (score 37):

Might I suggest a slight edit to the currently accepted answer:

```
function insertSpaces(string) {
    string = string.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1 $2');
    string = string.replace(/([A-Z])([A-Z][a-z])/g, '$1 $2')
    return string;
}
```

This means that:

```
ACROText -> ACRO Text
UserNameTest -> User Name Test
```

Which might be slightly more useful if you are dealing with db column names (And are using acronyms for some things)

Comment: This works perfectly for what I was needing. It perfectly added a space between capital letters but kept acronyms together.

Answer (score 10):

Here is what i ended up using to convert a string to a title case, based on a few of the answers here:

```
str = str
  .replace(/(_|-)/g, ' ')
  .trim()
  .replace(/\w\S*/g, function(str) {
    return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.substr(1)
  })   
  .replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1 $2')
  .replace(/([A-Z])([A-Z][a-z])/g, '$1 $2')
```

Here is a JSFiddle where you can test your string to see if this meets your needs:
https://jsfiddle.net/thomastasa/5236dv8t/85/

---

Examples:

- "yourStringHere" -> "Your String Here"
- "AnotherStringHere" -> "Another String Here"
- "someones_string" -> "Someones String"
- "Another-String-Here" -> "Another String Here"
- "myAWESOMEString" -> "My AWESOME String"

Comment: As for right now, substr() is already deprecated is there any alternative for this method?

Answer (score 8):

This should insert a space between each capital letter that was not preceded by a capital letter.

```
var myString = "MySites"
var newString = "";
var wasUpper = false;
for (var i = 0; i < myString.length; i++)
{
    if (!wasUpper && myString[i] == myString.toUpperCase()[i])
    {
        newString = newString + " ";
        wasUpper = true;
    }
    else
    {
        wasUpper = false;
    }
    newString = newString + myString[i];
}
```

`newString` will have the value you want. Also, if you want to shorten your code using regex, you can use the following code from [Javascript camelCase to Regular Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4149276/javascript-camelcase-to-regular-form)

```
"thisStringIsGood"
    // insert a space before all caps
    .replace(/([A-Z])/g, ' $1')
    // uppercase the first character
    .replace(/^./, function(str){ return str.toUpperCase(); })
```

Answer (score 5):

regex to find lower case - upper case boundary then insert a space

```
<div id='x'>ThisIsMySites</div>
$('#x').text( $('#x').text().replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, "$1 $2") );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uXy64/

Answer (score 4):

In a single regex replace (without trims or joins) that allows any character not just letters `[a-z]` or `[A-Z]`.

```js
const str = "MySites";
str.replace(/(?<!^)([A-Z])/g, " $1"); // -> "My Sites"
```

You can check more about the look behind `(?<!^)` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15669590/6201659).

Edit:

Added the global `/g` flag to be able to do multiple replacements.

Comment: If you add `g` flag, the regex will also work on adjacent capital letters.   'ThisIsATest'.replace(/(?<!^)([A-Z])/g, ' $1') === 'This Is A Test'

Comment: @NitsanBenHanoch nice catch, i forgot global search flag.

Answer (score 4):

This is another possibility, way much compact

```
export function replaceCamelSpaces(colorName){
   return colorName.replace(/\B([A-Z])\B/g, ' $1');
}
```

Explained :

\B uppercase word boundary to find, for more read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664151/difference-between-b-and-b-in-regex)

([A-Z]) finding zero, one or more occurence of Upper letters

\B as before but at the end of the search

/g match all occurences of previous matches

replace with

' $1'

Replace with some letter(lowacase) and a space at beginning

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`String#split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and a look-ahead for the capitalized alphabet (`[A-Z]`) and then [`Array#join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the array with a space:

```js
let stringCamelCase = "MySites";

let string = stringCamelCase.split(/(?=[A-Z])/).join(" ");

console.log(string)
```

Or, as a String Object function:

```js
String.prototype.cC2SC = function() {
  return this.split(/(?=[A-Z])/).join(" ");
}

console.log("MyCamelCase".cC2SC());
```