# Difference between \b and \B in regex

Tags: regex

I am reading a book on regular expression and I came across this example for `\b`:

> The cat scattered his food all over the room.

Using regex - `\bcat\b` will match the word `cat` but not the `cat` in `scattered`.

For `\B` the author uses the following example:

> Please enter the nine-digit id as it
>
> appears on your color - coded pass-key.

Using regex `\B-\B` matches `-` between the word `color - coded`. Using `\b-\b` on the other hand matches the `-` in `nine-digit` and `pass-key`.

How come in the first example we use `\b` to separate `cat` and in the second use `\B` to separate `-`? Using `\b` in the second example does the opposite of what it did earlier.

Please explain the difference to me.

EDIT: Also, can anyone please explain with a new example?

Comment: what book do you read? maybe can help others to learn regex

Comment: @YohanesAI The book was Sams Teach Yourself Regular Expressions in 10 Minutes by Ben Forta

Answer (score 144, accepted):

The confusion stems from your thinking `\b` matches spaces (probably because "b" suggests "blank").

`\b` matches the empty string at the *beginning or end of a word*.  `\B` matches the empty string not at the beginning or end of a word.  The key here is that "-" is not a part of a word.  So `<left>-<right>` matches `\b-\b` because there are word boundaries on either side of the `-`.  On the other hand for `<left> - <right>` (note the spaces), there are not word boundaries on either side of the dash.  The word boundaries are one space further left and right.

On the other hand, when searching for `\bcat\b` word boundaries behave more intuitively, and it matches " cat " as expected.

Comment: Yes, I was indeed confusing \b with a blank space. However, I still feel a little confused. Can I ask you for one more example?

Comment: The key is that `-` is not considered part of a word.  Similarly, `!` is not a part of a word.  So again `\b!\b` matches "uunet!iamold", but not "Wow! You are."  You can try this stuff out at http://regexpal.com.

Comment: @andrewdski In my case \b catches also for punctuations...  I tried with \b[A-Z0-9]+\b on 1987894, 3219800; 234567, 345261. and it works fine, I obtain only numbers

Comment: Just adding that a work in regex is composed of letters (a– z and A– Z), digits, and the “_” [underscore]). Everything else is non word.

Comment: Could someone elaborate this line `\B matches the empty string not at the beginning or end of a word`

Comment: I'd stress **boundaries** a bit more, maybe typographically, even better to move the right hint (*b* means *boundary*) to the top of the answer.

Comment: \B is the negated version of \b

Answer (score 99):

`\b` is a zero-width word boundary. Specifically:

> Matches at the position between a word character (anything matched by \w) and a non-word character (anything matched by [^\w] or \W) as well as at the start and/or end of the string if the first and/or last characters in the string are word characters.

Example: `.\b` matches `c` in `abc`

`\B` is a zero-width non-word boundary. Specifically:

> Matches at the position between two word characters (i.e the position between \w\w) as well as at the position between two non-word characters (i.e. \W\W).

Example: `\B.\B` matches `b` in `abc`

See [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) for more great regex info

Comment: +1 because zero-width is an important part of the definition. If it weren't zero-width, then it would also grab those word/non-word characters in the matching part of the pattern.

Comment: In other words, \B matches the spot between \W and \W or between \w and \w, but not between \W and \w.

Comment: This answer has been added to the [Stack Overflow Regular Expression FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496), under "Anchors".

Comment: Following up on this: @Bohemian why is it that in JS
`"abc def".match(/\b./)` returns `['a']` as opposed to what [http://www.regular-expressions.info/refwordboundaries.html] (Your source: regex.info) says `['a', ' ', 'd']`.

Comment: @stephenhuh `string.match()` returns only the first match, unless you add the *global* flag `g`: `"abc def".match(/\b./g)` returns `['a', ' ', 'd']`

Comment: I think this is the better answer. I should also be the accepted one because it resolves the confusion. Much more to learn here.

Answer (score 69):

With a different example:

Consider this is the string and pattern to be searched for is 'cat':

`text = "catmania thiscat thiscatmaina";`

Now definitions,

**'\b'** finds/matches the pattern at the beginning or end of each word.

**'\B'** does not find/match the pattern at the beginning or end of each word.

Different Cases:

**Case 1: At the beginning of each word**

`result = text.replace(/\bcat/g, "ct");`

Now, result is "ctmania thiscat thiscatmaina"

**Case 2: At the end of each word**

`result = text.replace(/cat\b/g, "ct");`

Now, result is "catmania thisct thiscatmaina"

**Case 3: Not in the beginning**

`result = text.replace(/\Bcat/g, "ct");`

Now, result is "catmania thisct thisctmaina"

**Case 4: Not in the end**

`result = text.replace(/cat\B/g, "ct");`

Now, result is "ctmania thiscat thisctmaina"

**Case 5: Neither beginning nor end**

`result = text.replace(/\Bcat\B/g, "ct");`

Now, result is "catmania thiscat thisctmaina"

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong please, but, when using \bcat\b, if our string would have been, for example: "catcat is my cat" => the first word (catcat) would have applied to this condition. no?.

Comment: @Kosem this is a good question and made me study `\b` better. What I understood after is that the reason why the first word doesn't match is that with `\bcat\b` you are saying that cat must be surrounded by word boundaries. `catcat` starts with a word boundary, the first inner `cat` is found [we are still respecting the regex] but then the tail `\b` is imposing that after the first `t` in `catcat` there should be another word boundary, which is NOT the case because the second `c` in `catcat` is another word character [= word goes on]. Similar reason for skipping the second `cat` of `catcat`

Answer (score 11):

The metacharacter \b is an anchor like the caret and the dollar sign. It matches at a position that is called a "word boundary". This match is zero-length.

There are three different positions that qualify as word boundaries:

- Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a word character.
- After the last character in the string, if the last character is a word character.
- Between two characters in the string, where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.

**\B is the negated version of \b**. \B matches at every position where \b does not. Effectively, \B matches at any position between two word characters as well as at any position between two non-word characters.

Source: http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Answer (score 7):

[Source](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-boundaries.html) © Copyright RexEgg.com

**Word Boundary: \b***

The word boundary \b matches positions where one side is a word character (usually a letter, digit or underscore—but see below for variations across engines) and the other side is not a word character (for instance, it may be the beginning of the string or a space character).

The regex \bcat\b would, therefore, match cat in a black cat, but it wouldn't match it in catatonic, tomcat or certificate. Removing one of the boundaries, \bcat would match cat in catfish, and cat\b would match cat in tomcat, but not vice-versa. Both, of course, would match cat on its own.

**Not-a-word-boundary: \B**

\B matches all positions where \b doesn't match. Therefore, it matches:

✽ When neither side is a word character, for instance at any position in the string $=(@-%++) (including the beginning and end of the string)

✽ When both sides are a word character, for instance between the H and the i in Hi!

This may not seem very useful, but sometimes \B is just what you want. For instance,

✽ \Bcat\B will find cat fully surrounded by word characters, as in certificate, but neither on its own nor at the beginning or end of words.

✽ cat\B will find cat both in certificate and catfish, but neither in tomcat nor on its own.

✽ \Bcat will find cat both in certificate and tomcat, but neither in catfish nor on its own.

✽ \Bcat|cat\B will find cat in embedded situation, e.g. in certificate, catfish or tomcat, but not on its own.

Answer (score 4):

\b is used as word boundary

```
word = "categorical cat"
```

Find all "cat" in the above word

without \b

```
re.findall(r'cat',word)
['cat', 'cat']
```

with \b

```
re.findall(r'\bcat\b',word)
['cat']
```

Answer (score 3):

`\b` matches a word-boundary. `\B` matches non-word-boundaries, and is equivalent to <s>`[^\b]`</s>`(?!\b)` <sub><sup>(thanks to [@Alan Moore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20938/alan-moore) for the correction!)</sup></sub>. Both are **zero-width.**

See http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html for details. The site is extremely useful for many basic regex questions.

Comment: `\B` is **not** equivalent to `[^\b]`.  A character class (`[...]` or `[^...]`) consumes exactly one character, while zero-width assertions like `\b` and `\B` don't consume anything.  If you put `\b` in a character class, it takes a completely different meaning: `[\b]` matches a backspace, and `[^\b]` matches any character *except* a backspace.  `\B` is really equivalent to `(?!\b)`.

Comment: @Alan thanks, you're completely correct - I was not awake this morning when I wrote that. Fixed.

Comment: ...but why anybody would want to match a backspace is beyond me. :D

Answer (score 3):

Let take a string like :

> XIX IXI XX X I II IIXX XXII I-I X-X -X X- X-I I-X -X- -I-X -X-I I-X- X-I- X_X _X-

**Note:** Underscore ( _ ) is not considered a special character in this case.

1. `/\bX\b/g` Should begin and end with a special character or white Space

> XIX IXI XX **X** I II IIXX XXII I-I **X**-**X** -**X** **X**- **X**-I I-**X** -**X**- -I-**X** -**X**-I I-**X**- **X**-I- X_X _X-

---

2. `/\bX/g` Should begin with a special character or white Space

> **X**IX IXI **X**X **X** I II IIXX **X**XII I-I **X**-**X** -**X** **X**- **X**-I I-**X** -**X**- -I-**X** -**X**-I I-**X**- **X**-I- **X**_X _X-

---

3. `/X\b/g` Should end with a special character or white Space

> XI**X** IXI X**X** **X** I II IIX**X** XXII I-I **X**-**X** -**X** **X**- **X**-I I-**X** -**X**- -I-**X** -**X**-I I-**X**- **X**-I- X_**X** _**X**-

---

4. `/\BX\B/g` 
    Should *not* begin and *not* end with a special character or white Space

> XIX I**X**I XX X I II II**X**X X**X**II I-I X-X -X X- X-I I-X -X- -I-X -X-I I-X- X-I- X_X _X-

---

5. `/\BX/g` Should *not* begin with a special character or white Space

> XI**X** I**X**I X**X** X I II II**XX** X**X**II I-I X-X -X X- X-I I-X -X- -I-X -X-I I-X- X-I- X_**X** _**X**-

---

6. `/X\B/g` Should *not* end with a special character or white Space

> **X**IX I**X**I **X**X X I II II**X**X **XX**II I-I X-X -X X- X-I I-X -X- -I-X -X-I I-X- X-I- **X**_X _X-

---

7. `/\bX\B/g` Should begin and *not* end with a special character or white Space

> **X**IX IXI **X**X X I II II**X**X **X**XII I-I X-X -X X- X-I I-X -X- -I-X -X-I I-X- X-I- **X**_X _X-

---

8. `/\BX\b/g` Should *not* begin and should end with a special character or white Space

> XI**X** IXI X**X** X I II IIX**X** XXII I-I X-X -X X- X-I I-X -X- -I-X -X-I I-X- X-I- X_**X** _**X**-

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html :

> There are three different positions that qualify as word boundaries for `\b`:
>
> 1. Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a word character `\w`.
> 2. After the last character in the string, if the last character is a word character `\w`.
> 3. Between two characters in the string, where one is a word character `\w` and the other is not a word character `\W`.

To have a better understanding of `\b`, I'd like to consider the string by putting the word boundaries on it using arrows.

[Click this link for the array visualization of the string - 'THE CAT SCATTERED'.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECWg1.png)

[Click this link for the array visualization of the string - 'THE NINE-DIGIT COLOR - CODED PASS-KEY'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sqz8R.png)

In the string `THE CAT SCATTERED`

- The word boundary at `index 0` is assigned by following the `condition 1` mentioned above.
- The word boundary at `index 16` is assigned by following the `condition 2`.
- The word boundaries at `indices 2, 4, 6 and 8` are assigned by following the `condition 3`.

In the string `THE NINE-DIGIT COLOR - CODED PASS-KEY`

- The word boundary at `index 0` is assigned by following `condition 1`.
- All the remaining word boundaires are assigned by following the `condition 3`. Note here that since the string ends with a  '`.`' character (which is not a word character `\w`), the `condition 2` is not applied.

A similar array visualization can be done for non-word boundary `\B` using following the condition:

(Credits: Check [@Ganesh M S's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58261061/15083075) answer for the same quesiton)

> `\B` matches all positions where `\b` doesn't match, i.e:
>
> 1. When neither side is a word character (i.e when both sides are `\W`), for instance at any position in the string $=(@-%++) (including the beginning and end of the string)
> 2. When both sides are a word character `\w`, for instance between the H and the i in Hi!

Answer (score 0):

`\B` is *not* `\b` e.g. **negative** `\b`

`pass-key` here is no word boundary beside `-` so it matches `\B` in your first example there are word boundary beside cat so it matches `\b`

similar rules apply for others too. `\W` is negative of `\w` `\UPPER CASE` is negative of `\LOWER CASE`