# Why can't regular expressions match for @ sign?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

For the string `Be there @ six.`

Why does this work:

```
str.gsub! /\bsix\b/i, "seven"
```

But trying to replace the @ sign doesn't match:

```
str.gsub! /\b@\b/i, "at"
```

Escaping it doesn't seem to work either:

```
str.gsub! /\b\@\b/i, "at"
```

Comment: @aliteralmind That post doesn't appear to mention '@'.

Comment: @aliteralmind I tried escaping it as follows and it still seemed to fail to match: `/\b\@\b/i`

Comment: Actually, it's a word-boundary issue. Not an escaping issue. Unless there's a word ending immediately before it, or starting immediately after it, it won't match. Relevant question in the [StackOverflow Regular Expression FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean/22944075#22937618): [\b:word boundary, and \B:non-word boundary](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6664167), listed under category "Anchors", about a 1/4 way down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is down to how `\b` is interpreted. `\b` is a "word boundary", wherein a zero-length match occurs if `\b` is preceded by or followed by a *word character*. The word characters are limited to `[A-Za-z0-9_]` and maybe a few other things, but `@` is not a word character, so `\b` won't match just before it (and after a space). The space itself is not the boundary.

[More about word boundaries...](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)

If you need to replace the `@` with surrounding whitespace, you can capture it after the `\b` and use backreferences. This captures preceding whitespace with `\s*` for *zero or more* space characters.

```
str.gsub! /\b(\s*)@(\s*)\b/i, "\\1at\\2"
=> "Be there at six"
```

Or to insist upon whitespace, use `\s+` instead of `\s*`.

```
str = "Be there @ six."
str.gsub! /\b(\s+)@(\s+)\b/i, "\\1at\\2"
=> "Be there at six."

# No match without whitespace...
str = "Be there@six."
str.gsub! /\b(\s+)@(\s+)\b/i, "\\1at\\2"
=> nil
```

At this point, we're starting to introduce redundancies by forcing the use of `\b`. It could just as easily by done with `/(\w+\s+)@(\s+\w+)/`, foregoing the `\b` match for `\w` word characters followed by `\s` whitespace.

#### Update after comments:

If you want to treat `@` like a "word" which may appear at the beginning or end, or inside bounded by whitespace, you may use `\W` to match "non-word" characters, combined with `^$` anchors with an "or" pipe `|`:

```
# Replace @ at the start, middle, before punctuation
str = "@ Be there @ six @."
str.gsub! /(^|\W+)@(\W+|$)/, '\\1at\\2'
=> "at Be there at six at."
```

`(^|\W+)` matches either `^` the start of the string, or a sequence of non-word characters (like whitespace or punctuation). `(\W+|$)` is similar but can match the end of the string `$`.

Comment: I see. Is there a way to get the same result as using the `\b` word boundary to replace `@`?

Comment: That wouldn't work -- since it would also match the @ in `Be there@six`

Comment: you can use `\s+` instead then, but it insists upon whitespace

Comment: I see. Not quite the same result as `\b` provides, but close.

Comment: i.e. `\s+` would still fail if @ is at the beginning or end of the string (or ends with a punctuation mark).

Comment: @user3188544 `\b` would also fail if `@` were at the beginning or end of the string. What _exactly_ are you criteria?

Comment: `\b` does work for beginning and end of the strings (ex: `"test 123".gsub(/\btest\b/i, "")`). The criteria is if it occurs as word would.

Comment: `\b` works for the beginning of the string _if followed by a `\w`_ character. Please include specific examples above of what should and should not match, though I think I'm starting to understand.

Comment: @user3188544 I put another solution above, which I think meets your need as I now understand it.

Answer (score 1):

`\b` matches a word boundary, which is where a word character is next to a non-word character. In your string the `@` has a space on each side, and neither `@` or space are word characters so there is no match.

Compare:

```
'be there @ six'.gsub /\b@\b/, 'at'
```

produces

```
'be there @ six'
```

(i.e. no changes)

but

```
'be there@six'.gsub /\b@\b/, 'at' # no spaces around @
```

produces

```
"be thereatsix"
```

Also

```
'be there @ six'.gsub /@/, 'at' # no word boundaries in regex
```

produces

```
"be there at six"
```

Comment: Matt problem is that `'be there@six'.gsub /@/, 'at'` would also match. Is there a way to get the same result as using a word boundary?

Comment: @user3188544 the simplest way is probably just to match on whitespace around the `@`.

Comment: @user3188544 something like `/(?:\A|(?<=\W))@(?:(?=\W)|\z)/` might be a kind of “word boundary for `@`” but it really depends on exactly what you’re trying to do.