# Regex matching on word boundary OR non-digit

Tags: regex, word-boundary, word-boundaries

I'm trying to use a Regex pattern (in Java) to find a sequence of 3 digits and only 3 digits in a row.  4 digits doesn't match, 2 digits doesn't match.

The obvious pattern to me was:

```
"\b(\d{3})\b"
```

That matches against many source string cases, such as:

```
">123<"
" 123-"
"123"
```

But it won't match against a source string of "abc123def" because the c/1 boundary and the 3/d boundary don't count as a "word boundary" match that the \b class is expecting.

I would have expected the solution to be adding a character class that includes both non-Digit (\D) and the word boundary (\b).  But that appears to be illegal syntax.

```
"[\b\D](\d{3})[\b\D]"
```

Does anybody know what I could use as an expression that would extract "123" for a source string situation like:

```
"abc123def"
```

I'd appreciate any help.  And yes, I realize that in Java one must double-escape the codes like \b to \b, but that's not my issue and I didn't want to limit this to Java folks.

Comment: For more information, check out [`\b`:word boundaries](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6664167) (listed under "Anchors") and the whole section on "Lookarounds" in the [Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use lookarounds for those cases:

```
(?<!\d)(\d{3})(?!\d)
```

This means match 3 digits that are NOT followed and preceded by a digit.

#### [Working Demo](http://regex101.com/r/gB7cP6)

Answer (score 4):

Lookarounds can solve this problem, but I personally try to avoid them because not all regex engines fully support them.  Additionally, I wouldn't say this issue is complicated enough to merit the use of lookarounds in the first place.

You could match this: `(?:\b|\D)(\d{3})(?:\b|\D)`

Then return: `\1`

Or if you're performing a replacement and need to match the entire string: `(?:\b|\D)+(\d{3})(?:\b|\D)+`

Then replace with: `\1`

As a side note, the reason `\b` wasn't working as part of a character class was because within brackets, `[\b]` actually has a completely different meaning--it refers to a backspace, not a word boundary.

Here's a [Working Demo](http://regex101.com/r/jP1hG9).

Comment: That's a good answer.  The odd thing is, I tried that and came up empty handed in my unit tests.  I must have munged it up somehow.  I'll give it another shot.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, had to make a slight edit.  The second pattern needs to use `+` instead of `*` or else it will match the first three digits of a of a string of four digits or more.

Comment: Yeah - I came across that problem since I was actually doing a replacement in my app.  Thanks for the update.