# Regular Expression almost perfect for a Numeric Value

Tags: c#, regex

I have this REGEX **almost** perfect ... It seems to handle everything *except* a number that leads with a negative sign and then a decimal. So if I enter:

```
-.2
```

I get an error -

Here is my Regex -- everything else I've tested works perfectly...

```
^(\+|-)?[0-9]{1,11}?(?:\.[0-9]{1,4})?$
```

This allows for:

- a number  up to 11 digits (99 Billion)
- positive or negative number
- up to 4 decimal places (optional)
- leading 0 before decimal point is optional - ***for positive numbers only***

These all work:

```
-0.2345
-10
12
.125
0.1245
5.555
25000000000 (aka 25 Billion)
25000000000.25
```

These do not work:

```
-.2
-.421
```

Comment: @JohnBupit - `.125` is in his list of things that work

Comment: But it mustn't: `".125".match(/^(\+|-)?[0-9]{1,11}?(?:\.[0-9]{1,4})?$/)`

Comment: another bug?  should `100000000000.0001` be legal?

Comment: @Hogan - No ... I don't want it to go over 100 Billion. Thanks to all... someone posted the following then deleted it... (and it seems to work perfectly!! Thanks to the mystery helper. I put it in production and moved on to my next issue... thanks to all for the quick and brilliant responses!!:  ^(\+|-)?\.?[0-9]{1,11}?(?:\.[0-9]{1,4})?$

Comment: @DanB - That answer is wrong, it will allow illegal numbers like `.2.2` that is why he deleted it (my comment).  Please use John's answer or my answer.  They still won't limit to less than 100 Billion but they are better.

Comment: Thank you Hogan!!! Updating production now... Much appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
^(\+|-)?[0-9]{0,11}?(?:\.[0-9]{1,4})?$
```

**Update:**

The above regex accepts strings `+`, `-` and  (the empty string). You can use a *lookahead*  to restrict those. The lookahead ensures there must be a character after the `+` or `-` sign.

**The correct solution is:**

```
^(\+|-)?(?=.{1})[0-9]{0,11}(?:\.[0-9]{1,4})?$
```

[**A working example:**](http://rubular.com/r/Z0mKbclKc7)

Strings accepted:

```
-0.2345
-10
12
.125
0.1245
5.555
-.2
-.421
```

Strings not accepted:

```
100000000000.0001
+
-

123456789012
1111111111.12345
+1.11.1
-2.
```

Comment: No, it's not. Change at `{0, 11}`.

Comment: This seems to work correctly on regexpal.com using the data provided.

Answer (score 20):

Regex can be expensive... Why not use Decimal.Parse or Float.parse?

Your current implementation would never work with alternate number styles, like European where . (dot) and , (comma) are interchanged ...whereas Decimal.Parse will:

```
string stringValue = "45.889,33";
CultureInfo currentCulture = Thread.CurrentCulture; //set this way up in the execution chain
decimal thenumber = Decimal.Parse(stringValue, currentCulture);
//thenumber = 45889.33 in us-en display format.
```

Numerical parsing is not a good application for regex, IMO.

Comment: Your answer is also a lot easier to understand than the Regex ones - and hence the code will be easier to maintain

Comment: @enorl76 - What would happen if the user entered 45,889.33 and then I used the "Decimal.Parse(stringValue, french_culture);" wouldn't it gen an error in that case?? Would I need something like Decimal.TryParse()  at that point?? (I'm not concerned with this being used in Europe in this instance, but want to know for my own edification.

Comment: @DanB: if the current culture is en-US, then the user's input would be properly input.  if the current culture is fr-FR, then "45.889,33" would also be properly input.  If you want "validation" then yes, Decimal.TryParse would inform you of validity, with respect to the current culture's NumericalFormat specifications.

Answer (score 2):

How about this bad boy:

```
^(\+|-)?([0-9]{1,11}?|)(?:\.[0-9]{1,4})?$
```

Seems to work =)

Comment: What does `**` mean?  I've never seen that before.  Or was that an attempt at bolding?  You can't format text inside a code block.

Comment: @Bobson - I think that is to show the changes but in regex it is very strange

Comment: it was bolded in the preview. I'll remove them

Answer (score 2):

My $.02

```
 ^(\+|-)?([0-9]{1,11}|)?(?:\.[0-9]{1,4})?$
```

Comment: Woldn't this match `-a.24`? (I didn't test it)

Comment: `[0-9]` limit to digits.

Comment: Oh, I see where I misread it.  `|)` is "Or nothing", not "or anything".

Comment: Why the **`"|)"`** ("or Nothing") followed by **`"?"`** (0 or 1), since they are effectively doing the same thing? And, I think if you change **`"{1,11}"`** to **`"{0,11}"`**, you can remove both **`"|"`** and **`"?"`**, so final would be: **`^(\+|-)?([0-9]{0,11})(?:\.[0-9]{1,4})?$`**

Comment: @KevinFegan - Try it.

Answer (score 2):

Keyword: The 0 is optional for **POSITIVE** numbers only.

You need separate statements for the positive and negative.

```
^(((\+?[0-9]{0,11})|(-[0-9]{1,11}))(?:\.[0-9]{1,4})*)$
```

Comment: someone posted the following and then deleted it right away -- it seems to work perfectly... I'd like to give him credit, but his answer is gone.... ^(\+|-)?\.?[0-9]{1,11}?(?:\.[0-9]{1,4})?$

Comment: Your accepted answer does not force a 0 before the decimal point on negative numbers. This Regex now works correctly.

Comment: Thanks to @Hogan I see that answer is not quite right... it allows for 2 decimal points... I have accepted the answer from "John Bupit"... seems perfect... no time to test rest due to deadline.... but thanks for the help!

Comment: Which expression allows two decimal points? Mine does not and is still the only expression here that does not allow a negative number without a leading 0.

Answer (score 2):

All of your problems can be solved using a [word boundary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6664151/7586) in the right place:

```
^(?:\+|-\b)?[0-9]{0,11}(?:\.[0-9]{1,4})?\b$
```

- Changed `{1,11}` to `{0,11}` to allow zero digits before the decimal point.
- `\b` after the minus sigh would not allow the decimal point immediately next to it.
- `\b` at the end would not allow `"+"` or `"-"` as the whole string.

Working example (adapted from John): http://rubular.com/r/c7YLR25r3i