# ASP.NET Regex.Replace expression and method to replace all enclosed . characters

Tags: asp.net, regex, vb.net

I have this string:

`The.Soundcraft.Si.Performer.1.is.digital.19.3.inch.mix.actually this is. a test`

In this string I want to replace `.` characters that have a character directly before AND after it with `.` (so a trailing space) UNLESS the leading or trailing character is a number or space.

The end result would be:

`The. Soundcraft. Si. Performer. 1.is. digital. 19.3. inch. mix. actually this is. a test`

I tested my regex `([^0-9 ])\.([^0-9 ])` here: http://www.regexr.com/ and it seems to match all parts I need replaced.

So I coded this:

```
dim description as String = "The.Soundcraft.Si.Performer.1.is.digital.19.3.inch.mix.actually this is. a test"
description = Regex.Replace(description, "([^0-9 ])\.([^0-9 ])", ". ")
```

But nothing happens. What am I missing?

Comment: Try `description = Regex.Replace(description, "\b\.\b", ". ")`

Comment: Missing `@` in beginning of your regex. Should be `@"([^0-9 ])\.([^0-9 ])"`.

Comment: @noob: If it is VB.NET, `@` should not be used.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: There is `asp.net` tag too.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Thanks! You're suggestion works...although I'm unsure why (I was reading this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664151/difference-between-b-and-b-in-regex). Is `\b` just excluding numbers (which I want) or also (some) special characters (which I don't want)?

Comment: `\b` is a so-called word boundary. Read all about it here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Comment: @noob asp.net tag doesn't make answering a VB question with C# syntax useful. From the code given by the OP it' seems pretty obvious to me which language this is. Unless Microsoft decided to add Dim to C# as a keyword while I was asleep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
description = Regex.Replace(description, "\b\.\b", ". ")
```

The [regex demo here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cb%5C.%5Cb&i=The.Soundcraft.Si.Performer.1.is.digital.19.3.inch.mix.actually%20this%20is.%20a%20test&r=.%20)

[image]

*Why does it work?*

The word boundary `\b` can have 4 meanins depending on the context:

- `(?<!\w)` in a construct like `\b` + word letter (`[\p{L}\p{N}_]`)
- `(?<!\W)` in a construct like `\b` + non-word letter (`[^\p{L}\p{N}_]`)
- `(?!\w)` in a construct like word letter (`[\p{L}\p{N}_]`) + `\b`
- `(?!\W)` in a construct like non-word letter (`[^\p{L}\p{N}_]`) + `\b`.

In your case, the 2nd and 4th cases apply: the `.` is a non-word character, thus `\b\.\b` is the same as `(?<!\W)\.(?!\W)`: match a dot that is enclosed with word characters.

**EDGE CASE**:

If you do not want to replace `.` that is next to `_`, you need to exclude the `_` from the word boundary, and this is how it would look then:

```
(?<![^\p{L}\p{N}])\.(?![^\p{L}\p{N}])
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C!%5B%5E%5Cp%7BL%7D%5Cp%7BN%7D%5D)%5C.(%3F!%5B%5E%5Cp%7BL%7D%5Cp%7BN%7D%5D)&i=The_.Soundcraft._Si.Performer.1.is.digital.19.3.inch.mix.actually%20this%20is.%20a%20test&r=.%20)