# Regex: Confusion about \b behavior

Tags: regex, coffeescript, atom-editor

I am writing my own grammar for the Atom editor. It uses regular expressions to identify code that should be highlighted.

I'm want to highlight hex numbers in two formats:

```
$affe     // hex number with ampersand
0xeffa    // hex number with 0x
```

So I came up with this regex:

```
(\$|0x)[A-Fa-f0-9]+
```

Pretty straightforward, this works fine. The problem is that this will also highlight something like `0x0` in `t0x0t`. So I modified my regex to

```
\b(\$|0x)[A-Fa-f0-9]+\b
```

Now, this regex will only match `0xeffa` but not `$affe`, or any other number prefixed with $ - why is that? I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664151/difference-between-b-and-b-in-regex) that seems to be a similar problem. I assume this is because `$` is a non-word character. Is there a way to modify this regex so it matches both `0xeffa` and `$affe` but not `0x0` in `t0x0t`?

One solution that I tried is to simply write two separate regex expression for each case - it works but it somehow seems to defeat the purpose of regex expressions.

Comment: Put `\b` inside `(\$|\b0x)[A-Fa-f0-9]+\b`

Comment: `\b` marks the transition between a word character `[A-Za-z0-9_]` and a non-word character. But `$` is a non-word character, while `0` is a word-character. So putting it in front of the `($|0x)` would only match the $ if it's preceded by a word character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change position of where `\b` applies:

```
(\$|\b0x)[A-Fa-f0-9]+\b
```

Otherwise with `\b` preceding `$` engine expects a word character from set `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` appears right before `$` i.e. `a$af00`