# replaceAll or regex java forward slash

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I want to change the string "S/" to "S/." only whole word , I tried with Pattern.compile and Matcher.quoteReplacement. I didn't find the solution.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String cadena = "Moneda Actual : S/";
    cadena = cadena.replaceAll("\\bS/\\b", "S/.");
    System.out.println(cadena);
}
```

This code print :

> Moneda Actual : S/

I want to print :

> Moneda Actual : S/.

So if original text is `"Moneda Actual : S/."` , the algorithm mustn't replace to `"S/.."`

Comment: “I tried with Pattern.compile and Matcher.quoteReplacement.”  Edit your question and show the code you tried.

Comment: You can use `replaceAll(string, "S\/", "S\/\.");`

Comment: What do you mean by whole word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a negative look ahead:

```
cadena = cadena.replaceAll("\\bS/(?!\\.)", "S/.");
```

The negative look ahead asserts (without consuming) that the next character is not a dot.

This will also work then `"S/"` occurs at the end of the String.

——

There is no word boundary after a slash and before a dot. Word boundaries are between “word” characters (letters, number and the underscore) and non-“word” characters. Not between whitespace and non-whitespace.

Comment: Great solution, also takes care of "S\.S\S\S\."

Comment: @Wow `\b` (coded as `"\\b"` in a String literal) is a “word boundary”. It will prevent `"XS/"` from matching. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6664167/256196) for a full description.