# setting state with previous state and regex

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don´t understand how this code works. How does it set the state using the regex? And most importantly, how does it know to set the state using the result variable?

```
handleClick(evt) {
    const id = evt.target.id;
    const result = evt.target.value;
this.setState(prevState => ({
        value: `${prevState.value}${result}`
          .replace(/([/+\-/*=])([/+\-*=])/g, "$2")
          .replace(/^0+(?=[1-9])/, "")
          .replace(/^0+(?=\.)/, "0")
          .replace(/^0+\B/, "")
      })); 
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this code do the following:
1. Concatenate `prevState.value` and `evt.target.value` into single string (learn more about [ES6 Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals))
2. Replace all combinations like `++`, `+-`, `+*`, `+=`, `-+`, `--`, `-*`, `-=`, `*+`, `*-`, `**`, `*=`, `=+`, `=-`, `=*`, `==` to it's second character (but I think there is error in the code, replace statement should be `([\+\-*=])([\+\-*=])`, learn more about [regex](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp))
3. Remove from string all number, that start with 0, like `0009`, `01`, etc.
4. Remove all words, that start with 0, like `0a`, `0000z`, etc.
5. Remove all `0` from string (learn more about [\B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664151/difference-between-b-and-b-in-regex))
6. Set result string to the `state.value` (learn more about [React setState()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate))

Comment: Thanks. Whats going me some trouble Is the concatenate bit.