# How do I skip a character getting between the string?

Tags: c#, regex, linq

I am very new to regular expression , I needed to get specific value from string contained between `' '`

Using regular expression was able to get the values but getting an exception when there is a third  `'` in between `' '`.

Variable *rule* contains the whole string

```
IEnumerable<string> possibleValues = Regex
    .Matches(rule, @"'(?<val>.*?)'")
    .Cast<System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match>()
    .Select(match => match.Groups["val"].Value)
    .ToArray();
```

When following string is passed

RULE: 'Street Address'
      must be 
             'Samir Complex, 4th Floor, St Andrew's Road, Bandra (West)' (default value)

Expected values was **Street Address** and  **Samir Complex, 4th Floor, St Andrew's Road, Bandra (West)**

but getting **Street Address** and  **Samir Complex, 4th Floor, St Andrew**

Comment: You have an apostroph `'` in the `Andrew's` and you match as *few* as possible - `.*?`, that's why regex stops on the first apostroph found

Comment: try `@"'(?<val>.*?)'\B"` pattern

Comment: yes thanks this works can you put it in answer so that i can accept this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When matching apostrophes you don't want to match *every one*: in your case `'` within `Andrew's` should be *skipped*. 
You can try checking for *word boundary*; see details at [Difference between \b and \B in regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664151/difference-between-b-and-b-in-regex)

```
@"'(?<val>.*?)'\B"
```

**Code:**

```
string[] possibleValues = Regex
  .Matches(rule, @"'(?<val>.*?)'\B")
  .Cast<Match>()
  .Select(match => match.Groups["val"].Value)
  .ToArray();
```