# Strange behaviour of word boundary `\b` and `\B` with special characters

Tags: regex, word-boundary

For regex `(456)\b` and input `123456   xyz` it works as expected and the output is 456. [Case 1.](https://regex101.com/r/oBJU1x/4).

For almost the same regex `(456)#\b` and input `123456#   xyz` I expected the output to be `456#`. Because `\b` should still match the end of the line after matching `#`.

But the regex engine failed to find a match. [Case 2](https://regex101.com/r/oBJU1x/5).

Strangely, it works for the regex **`(456)#\B`**. Notice the non-word boundary **\B** in this regex. [Case 3](https://regex101.com/r/oBJU1x/6). What does `\B` match here?

I went through [This answer for understanding `\b and \B`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664151/difference-between-b-and-b-in-regex) and seems like my understanding is right.

So why is it strange? What am I missing here? Why does `\B` work while `\b` doesn't in case 2 and case 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A word boundary asserts the position using the following regex - `(^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)`. A word here is anything in `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

So in your case, for the regex `(456)#\b`, trying to match the string `123456#   xyz` will fail since # and the space after it are BOTH non- words(there needs to be one word and one non-word for a boundary) and thereby not satisfying the above regex.

Amusingly, if you try adding a word after the # in the string, say `123456#b  xyz`, it'll match, like shown [here](https://regex101.com/r/oBJU1x/7)

Comment: Can you define `\B` like this `(^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)`  ?

Comment: Nope. That is \b. \B is the direct negation of \b. So whatever is not `\b`, will be \B. You can refer the explanation box on the right side of regex101.com for any regex to understand what exactly are the constituents of these anchors tokens.

Answer (score 1):

> A word character is a character from a-z, A-Z, 0-9, including the _
>   (underscore) character.

So the # is not a word character, so it is not followed by a word boundary

Comment: but `\b` is also supposed to match word boundary. which in this case is a space.

Comment: A word boundary is where a 'word' ends, and a 'non-word' will begin, a space is just one of many non-word characters

So where you have 456#, the word boundary is between 6 and #, as 6 is a word, and # is not

Answer (score 0):

A word boundary `\b` is defined as the point between a word and non word character. Assuming the standard C locale then # and space are both non word characters so there is no word boundary between them.