# Python: find the word in string

Tags: python

I want to find the word in string like this below:

```
kkk="I do not like that car."

if "like" in kkk:
    print("like")
elif "dislike" in kkk:
    print("dislike")
elif "hate" in kkk:
    print("hate")
elif "cool" in kkk:
    print("cool")
```

But since my code is very long, I would like to keep it shorter:

```
if "like" in kkk or "dislike" in kkk or "hate" in kkk or "cool" in kkk:
    #print "like" 
    #unable to do it this way
```

Then I tried to use another way, but it didn't work:

```
a=["like","dislike","hate","cool"]

if any(x in kkk for x in a):
    print(x)
    #NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Comment: Slightly strange and unusual choice of variable names...

Comment: why not a simple `for-loop` --> `for x in a: if x in kkk: print(x)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
>>> kkk="I do not like that car."
>>> a=["like","dislike","hate","cool"]
>>> print(*[x for x in a if x in kkk])
like
```

This list comprehension is same as the following :

```
for x in a:
    if x in kkk:
        print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop that iterates over the list. And change your variable names to something more meaningful.

```
kkk="I do not like that car."
wordlist =["like","dislike","hate","cool"]
for word in wordlist:
    if word in kkk:
         print(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

`any` won't return the found word; the best alternative is perhaps `next`:

```
keywords = ["like", "dislike", "hate", "cool"]
sentence = "I do not like that car."

try:
    word = next(k for k in keywords if k in sentence)
    print(word)
except StopIteration:
    print('Not found')
```

If you don't want to handle an exception and instead get `None`:

```
word = next((k for k in keywords if k in sentence), None)
```

Answer (score 0):

another way of doing this is using sets:

```
kkk="I do not like that car."
kkk_split = kkk.split(' ')
print({'like', 'dislike', 'hate', 'cool'}.intersection(kkk_split))
```

Comment: Note that `split` and set intersection won't necessarily yield the same result as `in`.

Comment: @deceze how so?

Comment: `'like' in 'He likes cars'` vs. `{'like'}.intersection({'He', 'likes', 'cars'})`…

Comment: indeed it does not work for sub-strings, but i think the author was asking for full words

Answer (score 0):

For your case, `in` keyword cause conflicting result. For example, the snippet below:

```
sentence = "I do dislike that car."
opinion = ["like","dislike","hate","cool"]
for word in opinion:
    if word in sentence:
        print(word)
```

prints both `like` and `dislike`. Instead, you can use regular expression zero-width word boundary [`\b`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6664167/11542188) for accurate result as:

```
import re

sentence = "I do dislike that car."
opinion = ["like","dislike","hate","cool"]
for word in opinion:
    if re.search(r'\b'+word+r'\b', sentence):
        print(word)
```

which prints `dislike` only.