# Grep regexp printing whole line instead of word match

Tags: regex, grep

I have a following command:

`grep -r theme.colors.* app`

Which should print all the files and all words that follow the regexp.

Expected output:

`app/components/dynamicForm/styles.js:    theme.colors.text.subtitle`

However, the output that I get is the following:

`app/components/dynamicForm/styles.js:    color:{ header: theme.colors.text.subtitle},`

Can you tell me where am I making mistake?

Comment: Add option `-o` as first step. Quote your regex. Take a look at [word boundaries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6664167/3776858).

Comment: Maybe try `"\btheme.colors.*(?=},)"`.

Comment: Try `grep -r -o 'theme\.colors\.[[:alnum:]_.]*' app`

Comment: I'd use `[^ }]*` for the character group before the `*`.