# remove lines that contain exact string in bash script with sed

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I'm trying to run a bash script that removes lines from a file with only the specific string I pass to it,  "***/home/ken/sed.txt***".

Current script which does nothing:

```
#!/bin/bash

script="\\/home\\/ken\\/sed.txt"

sed -i "/\<$script\>/d" /home/ken/sed.txt
```

This deletes all rows:

```
#!/bin/bash

script="\\/home\\/ken\\/sed.txt"

sed -i "/$script/d" /home/ken/sed.txt
```

The file:

```
1 1 1 1 1 /home/ken/sed.txt
6 6 6 6 6 /home/ken/sed.txt
2 2 2 2 2 /home/ken/sed.txt
6 6 6 6 6 /home/ken/sed.txt
3 3 3 3 3 /home/ken/sed.txt
3 3 3 3 3 /home/ken/sed.txt
5 5 5 5 5 /home/ken/sed.txt
1 1 1 1 1 a/home/ken/sed.txt
6 6 6 6 6 a/home/ken/sed.txt
2 2 2 2 2 a/home/ken/sed.txt
6 6 6 6 6 a/home/ken/sed.txt
3 3 3 3 3 a/home/ken/sed.txt
3 3 3 3 3 a/home/ken/sed.txt
5 5 5 5 5 a/home/ken/sed.txt
```

Desired outcome:

```
1 1 1 1 1 a/home/ken/sed.txt
6 6 6 6 6 a/home/ken/sed.txt
2 2 2 2 2 a/home/ken/sed.txt
6 6 6 6 6 a/home/ken/sed.txt
3 3 3 3 3 a/home/ken/sed.txt
3 3 3 3 3 a/home/ken/sed.txt
5 5 5 5 5 a/home/ken/sed.txt
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't abuse backslash.  `sed -e '\@/path/to/match@d'`

Comment: In the ideal case, it would be nice to specify exactly what characters would make `[char]/home/ken/sed.txt` a non-match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
script='/home/ken/sed.txt'
sed -n "\|\b$script|p" file
```

Output:

```
1 1 1 1 1 a/home/ken/sed.txt
6 6 6 6 6 a/home/ken/sed.txt
2 2 2 2 2 a/home/ken/sed.txt
6 6 6 6 6 a/home/ken/sed.txt
3 3 3 3 3 a/home/ken/sed.txt
3 3 3 3 3 a/home/ken/sed.txt
5 5 5 5 5 a/home/ken/sed.txt
```

I switched from `//`p to `\||p` to avoid escaping `/`.

From `man sed`:

> `\cregexpc`: Match lines matching the regular expression regexp.  The c may be any character.

See: [\b](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6664167/3776858)

Comment: This "works" in that it creates a new file with the desired outcome - I'd like it to edit the current file. Replacing -n with -ni or just -i doesn't work still

Comment: With GNU sed: If you want to edit your file "in place" add option `-i`. With non GNU sed try `-i ''`.

Comment: -i doesn't work. It appends the "desired output" to the end of sed.txt

edit: wait,  hold on.

Comment: Cancel that - looks like the order of the options is important. The correct way is -ni. I had -in. So: ```sed -ni "\|\b$script|p" /home/ken/sed.txt```

Thank you!

Comment: @soulkingbrook `-in` will uses `n` as the backup extension. Look for a `/home/ken/sed.txtn` file.

Answer (score 1):

As usual when wanting to edit a file in place, I recommend `ed` over `sed -i`:

```
#!/bin/sh
script=" /home/ken/sed.txt"
ed -s sed.txt <<EOF
g!$script!d
w
EOF
```

Note the addition of a space in your `$script` variable, to avoid matching the `a/home/ken/sed.txt` lines. Without that, every line in your example file is deleted, as you've seen.

Answer (score 0):

Why is sed needed? I think you could just grep with the "--fixed-strings" and the "--invert-match" option:

```
$ fgrep -v ' /home/ken/sed.txt' file.txt
1 1 1 1 1 a/home/ken/sed.txt
6 6 6 6 6 a/home/ken/sed.txt
2 2 2 2 2 a/home/ken/sed.txt
6 6 6 6 6 a/home/ken/sed.txt
3 3 3 3 3 a/home/ken/sed.txt
3 3 3 3 3 a/home/ken/sed.txt
5 5 5 5 5 a/home/ken/sed.txt

grep -F -v ' /home/ken/sed.txt' file.txt
```

Comment: Or, with GNU grep, `grep -vw '/home/ken/sed.txt'`