# How can I remove blank spaces in a file that are marked with "." without removing the decimal place in my numbers? (Bash shell)

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have a file that looks like this:

```
18 29 293.434
12 32 9954.343 
12 343 .
12 45 9493.545
```

I want to replace the "." on line 3 with "0" using sed.

I can't figure out how to do this without replacing every decimal place in the file.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you post expected output ? Seems a mismatch between the title and description...

Answer (score 4):

With GNU sed:

```
sed 's/\B\.\B/0/g' file
```

Output:

```
18 29 293.434
12 32 9954.343 
12 343 0
12 45 9493.545
```

---

See: [\B: non-word boundary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6664167/3776858)

Comment: For those wanting a posix compliant solution, perhaps `sed -E 's/(^|[[:space:]])[.]([[:space:]]|$)/\10\2/g' file`?

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box and assuming you want to replace `.` with `0` wherever it occurs alone in any field rather than just if it's in the last field of the 3rd line of input:

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i == ".") $i=0} 1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, if the dot is at the end, remove spaces and substitute this dot with 0:

```
sed '/\.$/{s/ //g;s/\.$/0/}' file
#       ^
```

`$` is an anchor, it means *at the end of the line*

```
18 29 293.434
12 32 9954.343
123430
12 45 9493.545
```