# Search string that contains WORD with \W or ^ before and \W or $ after

Tags: python, regex, python-re

How to simplify following regular expression

```
re.search(f'\W{word}\W', text) or re.search(f'^{word}\W', text) or re.search(f'\W{word}$', text) or word == text
```

i.e. return True for any string that contains word with \W or ^ before and \W or $ after.

Variants

1. `re.search(f'[^\W]{word}[\W$]', text)`
2. `re.search(f'[\W^]{word}[\W$]', text)`

dont work for my case.

Expression `re.search(f'\W*{word}\W*', text)` gives wrong matches, for example `word + 'A'`.

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: I think you're just looking for the `\b` pattern for a word boundary.

Comment: `$` doesn't have special meaning inside `[]`. And `^` at the beginning of `[]` means to invert the match -- it matches anything *except* those characters.

Comment: Why did you use `*` quantifiers after `\W`? That allows it to match nothing.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6664167/5527985) is explaining word boundaries well.

Comment: re.search(f"[\b\W]{word}[\b\W]", text) does not match cases in the title of question.The problem is not in word boundaries. Problem is that word can be at the start of string, but pattern \W{word}\W requires symbol before word.

Comment: @Che4ako The pattern is [`\bword\b`](https://regex101.com/r/oKXvtP/1) so you would use [`re.search(fr'\b{word}\b', text)`](https://tio.run/##JY2xCoAwDET3fEVwqYK4OPsnWRRbLGhSYkBF/PZKdbk73hsuXbYI9znHLYkaqgcwfxoOWB2iM7Gwx3@VRDuEmHgT/fFeAXxiQFfaASSNbLX6LkSex3Wtgzqa7mIfmlyL5aBpcn4B) a [word boundary](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)  is an *anchor* (zero length) it matches at a position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no simple way to make ^ or $ optional patterns in Python's regexps.

I think the easiest way will be to concatenate the three regexps, but using the `|` operator inside the expression instead of the external `or` with 3 .search calls:

```
word = re.escape(ticker.lower())
result = re.search(f"(^{word}\W)|(\W{word}\W)|(\W{word}$)"`
```

Comment: Thank you! I lost a lot of time trying to find non-existent ^ or $ optional pattern.