How to preserve whitespace with preg_replace if the match includes it?
So, I am having trouble with some PHP regex.
Here is my pattern: /(?:^|\W)(the)(?:$|\W)/i
This pattern will match any 'the' if it falls at the start of the string, end of the string, or in the middle. However, it will not match the letters 't', 'h', and 'e' if they are found in succession within words such as 'there'
Everything is fine until we do the replacement part of preg_replace
// All you need to know about $message is that it is a string of user input
// The content passed in will be sentences like "The fish jumped over the bridge"
// The resulting replacement should be "foo fish jumped over foo bridge"
// The current result would be "foofish jumped overfoobridge"

$message = "The fish jumped over the bridge"; // Would usually be user input, or from POST
$secretMsg = preg_replace('/(?:^|\W)(the)(?:$|\W)/i', 'foo', $message);
echo $secretMsg; // Should be  "foo fish jumped over foo bridge"

I have dug through the PHP regex manual, but have not found anything useful. I even tried making the replace '-foo-' and then replacing all '-' with ' '. However, this will obviously result in unnecessary whitespace to appear at the start and end of strings. Additionally, it still will not correctly match strings where two the's are in succession like "the the". This string will be matched to "foothe".
As you can see from my current pattern, I have played around with non-capturing and capturing groups. I have also played around with backreferences, but still no luck.
At this point, I am at a loss and need some guidance from someone who understands regex more than me. I want to also point out that I understand that whitespace will be matched in this expression and I WANT IT to be matched, but I DO NOT want it to be replaced.

Anything wrong with just using word boundaries?  That is, match on \bthe\b ?

$secretMsg = preg_replace('/\bthe\b/i', 'foo', $message); works for me. Explanation of word boundary here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6664167/256196

what would be the desired outcome for the the? foo or foo foo?

All you need is /\bthe\b/i, a word boundary. Yes, you may of course use /(?<!\w)(the)(?!\w)/iif you want, but I would not advise. Unless the is some placeholder. And even then I'd advise something different.

Thank you for the help! I can't tell you how long I looked for a solution. I was too focused on fixing how I was currently doing the pattern and not what the pattern was supposed to achieve.
