# How to insert space before capitalize character in a word using replace and regex in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

these are the words in array

```
    WorkNumber
    WorkType
    Version 
    Status
    Module
    Priority
    AssignedBy
    AssignedTo
    Subject 
    Details 
    EstimatedTime 
    ActualTime
    CreatedDate
    ModifiedDate
```

i need the output as following

```
Work Number
Work Type
Version 
Status
Module
Priority
Assigned By
Assigned To
Subject 
Details 
Estimated Time 
Actual Time
Created Date
Modified Date
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add a space before capital letter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582228/add-a-space-before-capital-letter)

Comment: jQuery is more about manipulating DOM elements. For string operations use standard [String methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/#Methods_unrelated_to_HTML).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is what you need :

```
"YourString".replace( /([a-z])([A-Z])/g, "$1 $2");
```

Will output :

```
"Your String"
```

Comment: There should be a `g` flag, just in case.