# How can I match a pattern as long as it's not at the beginning with regex?

Tags: regex, regex-negation

Assume the following strings:

```
aaa bbb ccc
bbb aaa ccc
```

I want to match `aaa` as long as it is not at the start of the string. I'm trying to negate it by doing something like this:

```
[^^]aaa
```

But I don't think this is right. Using `preg_replace`.

Comment: Are you only matching `aaa`?  Replacing it with what?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You can use a look behind to make sure it is not at the beginning. `(?<!^)aaa`

Comment: Anyway to negate the position assertion?

Comment: I still need to capture `aaa`. Just wrap in parenthesis?

Comment: For JavaScript only use (?!^)aaa

Comment: `[^\n]aaa` should also do the job (did the job for me) and is much simpler/can hence be used when you don't have lookbehinds available.

Comment: if you're doing this in R using `gsub()`, it works if you set the `perl = T` option

Answer (score 48):

Since I came here via Google search, and was **interested in a solution that is not using a lookbehind**, here are my 2 cents.

The [`[^^]aaa`](https://regex101.com/r/71Q093/1) pattern matches a character other than `^` and then 3 `a`s *anywhere* inside a string. The `[^...]` is a [*negated character class*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) where `^` is not considered a special character. Note the first `^` that is right after `[` is special as it denotes a negation, and the second one is just a literal caret symbol.

Thus, a `^` cannot be inside `[...]` to denote the start of string.

A solution is to use any negative lookaround, these two will work equally well:

```
(?<!^)aaa
```

and a lookahead:

```
(?!^)aaa
```

Why lookahead works, too? [Lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) are zero-width assertions, and anchors are zero-width, too - they consume no text. Literally speaking, `(?<!^)` checks if there is no start of string position immediately to the left of the current  location,  and `(?!^)` checks if there is no start of string position immediately to the right of the current location. The same *locations* are being checked, that is why both work well.

Comment: Thanks for the look-ahead alternative, as Javascript does not yet support look-behind.

Comment: The lookbehind support has already been introduced in ECMAScript 2018+, so you may use `(?<!^)` in Node.JS and Chrome, but `(?!^)` is still good in VBA that follows the ES5 standard and older JS environments including IE.

Comment: Lookbehinds are supported only in Chrome 62+ and Opera 49+ (https://caniuse.com/#feat=js-regexp-lookbehind)

Answer (score 16):

If you don't want to use lookbehind then use this regex:

```
/.(aaa)/
```

And use `matched group # 1`.

Comment: This is the best answer because it works with other dialects of regexp as well.

Comment: But unless your regex engine supports overlapping matches it won't match multiple occurrences of `aaa` after each other. `xaaaaaa` will only have one match.

Answer (score 5):

This situation is the first time that I've seen lookarounds outperform `\K`.  Interesting.

Typically capture groups and lookarounds cost additional steps.  But due to the nature of this task, the regex engine can navigate the string faster in search of the `aaa` then look back for a start of the string anchor.

I'll add a couple of `\K` patterns for comparison.

I am using the `s` pattern modifier in case the leading character might be a newline character (which `.` would not normally match).  I just thought I would add this consideration to preemptively address a fringe case that I may be posed.

Again, this is an enlightening scenario because in all other regex cases that I've dealt with `\K` beats out the other techniques.

Step Count Comparison Matrix:

```
              | `~.\Kaaa~s` | `~.+?\Kaaa~s` | `(?<!^)aaa` | `(?!^)aaa` | `.(aaa)` |
--------------|-------------|---------------|-------------|------------|----------|
`aaa bbb ccc` |   12 steps  |    67 steps   |   8 steps   |  8 steps   | 16 steps |
--------------|-------------|---------------|-------------|------------|----------|
`bbb aaa ccc` |   15 steps  |    12 steps   |   6 steps   |  6 steps   | 12 steps |
```

The take away is: To learn about the efficiency of your patterns, spit them into regex101.com and compare the step counts.

Also, if you *know* exactly what substring you are looking for and you don't need a regex pattern, then you should be using `strpos()` as a matter of best practice (and just check that the returned value is `> 0`)

...in other words:

```
if (strpos($haystack, 'aaa')) {
    // 'aaa' is "truthy"
    // 'aaa' is found and not positioned at offset zero
}
```

Comment: Useful advice about checking the efficiency of regex patterns in regex101.com.

Answer (score 3):

This will work to find what you are looking for:

`(?<!^)aaa`

Example in use: http://regexr.com?34ab2

Answer (score 1):

I came here looking at a solution for the re2 engine, used by google spreadsheets, which doesn't support lookarounds.
But the answers here gave me the idea of using the following.
I don't understand why i have to replace by the captured group but anyhow, it works.

> aaa bbb ccc
>   bbb aaa ccc

```
([^^])aaa
```

replace by:

```
$1zzz
```

reuslts in:

> aaa bbb ccc
>   bbb zzz ccc