# How to trim leading and trailing spaces from a string in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-textformfield

I have a 'textformfeild' that takes strings and I want to trim the white spaces at the begining and the end and strict the one in the middle to only one space.

for example if my string is like this:(....AB....CD.....) where the black dots represent the white spaces.

and I wanna make it look like this:(AB.CD)

any idea on how to do that?
this is what I tried to do:

```
userWeight!.trim()
```

but this will remove all the white spaces including the one in the middle

Comment: `trim()` should not remove stuff in the middle. Can you demonstrate this behaviour with an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`trim` will remove left and right spaces. You can use [RegExp](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/RegExp-class.html) to remove inner spaces:

```dart
void main(List<String> args) {
  String data = "       AB      CD   ";

  String result = data.trim().replaceAll(RegExp(r' \s+'), ' ');

  print(result); //AB CD
}
```

Comment: Others short form are described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38206425/10157127)

Comment: Thanks Yeasin, this is exactly the behaviour I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

`Trim` - If you use `trim()` this will remove only first and end of the white spaces `example`,

```
String str1 = "   Hello World  "; 
print(str1.trim());
```

The `output` will be only = `Hello World`

For your purpose you may use `replaceAll`

```
String str1 = "....AB....CD....."; 
print(str1.replaceAll("....","."));
```

The output will be = "`.AB.CD.`"

If you still want to remove first and last `.` use `substring`

```
String str1 = "....AB....CD....."; 
print(str1.replaceAll("....",".").substring( 1, str1.length() - 1 ));
```

The output will be = "`AB.CD`"

This is what your expected output is.

Answer (score 0):

Trim will remove white spaces before and after the string..

[image: preview]

Comment: Sorry maybe I was not actually very clear but I also wanted to insure that there will be only one space in the middle when i said "and strict the one in the middle to only one space." cause whaen I tried it with multiple spaces it only remove the ones at the begining and the end

Comment: for example (....AB....CD.....) came out as AB....CD but I wanted it to be AB.CD

Answer (score 0):

Trim will only remove the leading and trailing spaces or white space characters of a given string

Refer this for more:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String/trim.html

Comment: whr do u frm in India ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 String str = "  AB        CD  ";
  
  str = str.trim();
  while (str.contains("  ")) {
    str = str.replaceAll("  ", " ");
  }
  
  print(str);
```

[image]