# regex non-fixed-width lookaround

Tags: php, node.js, regex

I am trying to match curly quotes that are inside shortcodes and replace them with normal quotes but leave the ones outside.

Here is an example content:

```
“foobar” [tagname id=“1035” linked=“true”] “another” [tagname id=“1”]
```

Should output the following:

```
“foobar” [tagname id="1035" linked="true"] “another” [tagname id="1"]
```

It can be PCRE or Javascript regex. Any suggestions is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a little tricky, I am contributing from my end.

So, we can,

- match strings that follow a format of `=“some_chars”`
- Since you have an additional constraint of match only if they are inside the square brackets, we will use positive lookahead `?=` to match the above only if it is followed by a closing square bracket (since the string is uniformly formed, there will always be an opening square bracket which we won't bother about).

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$str = "outside=“bar” “foobar” [tagname id=“1035” linked=“true”] “another” [tagname id=“1”]";

echo preg_replace('/(\=“([^”]*)”)(?=[^[]*\])/', '="${2}"', $str);
```

[**Online Demo**](https://onecompiler.com/php/3yj53e2tt)

Answer (score 2):

For doing replacements on substrings that match some pattern it's often more efficient and comfortable to use a callback if available. With PHP and [`preg_replace_callback`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) e.g.:

```
$res = preg_replace_callback('~\[[^\]\[]*\]~', function($m) {
  return str_replace(['“','”'], '"', $m[0]);
}, $str);
```

[This pattern](https://regex101.com/r/BMwZEE/1) matches an opening square bracket followed by [any amount](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) of [characters that are no](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) square brackets, followed by a closing square bracket. The callback function replaces quotes.

[Here is a PHP demo](https://tio.run/##bY7BDoIwEETv/YqNISkaDhjjCYlXj9xLNbWuQoCWlHIyGj9Efo4fwcXEm5fNZHYmb9qinabdPjtkjAWdd5ACH1/vq7Vn5cbXAMKrm1ENQnlJ6bGON9vZrktT4dfxrkdyJJBWxvoC//bmCE8I4rAjSOvwdnLY1krjSau6PitdhfyZC3HMZS7kKpdPHsG1N9qX1oRBs4Q7A3Doe2eApv7qoZgX84juwGUEfEG9oBGxXCbsQZKypBjqwsKMT9g0fQA) at tio.run. This can easily be translated to [JS with `replace` function (demo)](https://tio.run/##bY1BCsIwEEX3OcXgplW0VUQQSr1IGiHWsVbTpKRpNyL0IHq5XiRO3LhxMTC8efP/TQ6yK23dutWw916hg85ZyCGaxtfFmJO00/gG7mSlZYNQn3M6bNbbXcCq1nf8Emd7JCKAdqmNu@Lfv6BEGWOhx2JHPdSWWGyVLDFOC86PhSi4WBQirZbQQH6ABwNyXW81ND@VU1xIIy2aRfOMPWlYaXRnFCbKVDHlE/L@Aw).

```
let res = str.replace(/\[[^\]\[]*\]/g, m => { return m.replace(/[“”]/g,'"'); });
```

---

Without callback in PCRE/PHP also the [`\G` anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14897949/what-is-the-use-of-g-anchor-in-regex) can be used to continue where the previous match ended. To chain matches to an opening square bracket (without checking for a closing).

```
$res = preg_replace('~(?:\G(?!^)|\[)[^“”\]\[]*\K[“”]~u', '"', $str);
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/3wgjOe/1) or [another PHP demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxj7AI4CLS6W4pEjBVkH9UcOctPz8pMSiRw1zFaJLEtPzEnNTFTJTbIEShgbGpiDhnMy87FSwSElRaSpQJFYByE7Myy/JSMWqD6RE3RpoSVFqMdCSgqLU9Pii1IKcxORUDfU6DXurGHcNe8U4zZqYaM3oOKAOoIaY2JjoWK0Y72gIN7auVF1HQV0JSICcqgk0LTU5I18BZKQ11///AA)

`(?!^)` [prevents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15669557/how-can-i-match-a-pattern-as-long-as-its-not-at-the-beginning-with-regex) `\G` from matching at start (default). [`\K` resets](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#K) beginning of the reported match.

---

To have it mentioned, another method could be to use a lookahead at each `“` `”` for checking if there is a closing `]` ahead without any other square brackets in between: [`[“”](?=[^\]\[]*\])`](https://regex101.com/r/NYgzPh/1)
This does not check for an opening `[` and works in all regex flavors that support lookaheads.

Comment: I have already tried this solution also but was wondering if there was a one-pass solution.

Comment: @voldomazta The other idea is good! However to avoid something [like this](https://regex101.com/r/mwmYcW/1), I think you better replace the lookahead `(?=.*\])` with `(?=[^\]\[]*\])` [like that](https://regex101.com/r/5hLZWl/1). If you read my full answer, there are two one-pass solutions however the other answer is more concise targeting the `=` (performance).

Comment: @bobblebubble Fixed my solution. Thanks for pointing out. Always feel free to ping my bugs!