# Is there a way I can change the contents of a variable in Camel Case to space separated words?

Tags: javascript

I have a variable which contains this:

```
var a = "hotelRoomNumber";
```

Is there a way I can create a new variable from this that contains: "Hotel Room Number" ?  I need to do a split on the uppercase character but I've not seen this done anywhere before.

Comment: Yes, but what do you want to do with strings like `"TMNT are so cool!"`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582228/insert-space-before-capital-letters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could use a regex, but it's simpler just to build a new string:

```
var a = "hotelRoomNumber";
var b = '';
if (a.length > 0) {
    b += a[0].toUpperCase();
    for (var i = 1; i != a.length; ++i) {
        b += a[i] === a[i].toUpperCase() ? ' ' + a[i] : a[i];
    }
}

// Now b === "Hotel Room Number"
```

Answer (score 1):

I have made a function here:

http://jsfiddle.net/wZf6Z/2/

```
function camelToSpaceSeperated(string)
{
    var char, i, spaceSeperated = '';

    // iterate through each char
    for (i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        char = string.charAt(i); // current char

        if (i > 0 && char === char.toUpperCase()) { // if is uppercase
            spaceSeperated += ' ' + char;
        } else {
            spaceSeperated += char;
        }
    }

    // Make the first char uppercase
    spaceSeperated = spaceSeperated.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + spaceSeperated.substr(1);

    return spaceSeperated;
}
```

The general idea is to iterate through each char in the string, check if the current char is already uppercased, if so then prepend a space to it.

Comment: extraneous space at beginning of string. "A" becomes " A".

Comment: thanks djechlin for pointing this out. Checking if it is the first char in the if condition or simply trimming the string before returning can do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = "mySampleString";
str = str.replace(/([A-Z])/g, ' $1').replace(/^./, function(str){ return str.toUpperCase(); });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PrashantJ/zX8RL/1/