# Javascript Strings; turn "NameSubname" into "Name Subname"

Tags: javascript, string

how to get this on javascript? given a name with no spaces `AndrewGonzalezPuerta` convert into this `Andrew Gonzalez Puerta`

Insert a `space` before every capital letter not counting the first one

Comment: This has already been [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25452019/5037430).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a regex solution using a lookahead to make sure that the capital letter is not at the beginning of the string.

```js
const name = "AndrewGonzalezPuerta";

console.log(name.replace(/(?!^)([A-Z])/g, " $1"));
```

Comment: `SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: invalid`

Comment: @MarkMeyer What Browser are you using?

Comment: @Luca I'm using the latest Safari

Comment: @MarkMeyer Thanks for the word. Can you try it again?

Comment: Yep, that did it @ggorlen. It's working here now.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Thanks. Do you recommend deleting this since the question has already been answered?

Comment: Honestly, @ggorlen, I'm not sure what the community view is on that. In an ideal world all questions would have one thread, but when I'm searching for something on SO I often find solutions in dupes that are better than the original. So I'm not sure. Might be a good question for https://meta.stackoverflow.com (if it's not already there).