# React convert array name to normal sentence

Tags: reactjs

I have displayed the name of the arrays in the UI and I'm trying to convert those as a normal sentence:
Example: thisIsArrayOne, thisIsArrayTwo => should be This Is Array One, This Is Array Two.

I'm using `toTitleCase` method but seems that is not working

```
<div>{name.toTitleCase()}</div>
```

Comment: How about Javascript solutions of this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5582228/4636715 . Btw, I could not get what exactly you mean by *array name* or *name of the arrays*

Comment: @vahdet yes, it's working. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
  let array=["thisIsArrayOneTwo","thisIsArrayTwo"];
   let newArray=array.map(r=>r.split(/(?=[A-Z])/).join(" "));
   console.log(newArray);
```

Code here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-v8ltfo

Comment: Thanks, it's working. Also need some CSS to capitalize the word and it's okay. :)

Comment: Could you mark the ans useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this --
This is React functional component .

```js
  

import React from 'react';
    
 const New = (props) =>{
    let val = ['thisIsArrayOne', 'thisIsArrayTwo'];
     const cheangeUpperCase = ()=>{
      
         let a =val.map((val, index)=>(  
            val= val.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + val.slice(1)
         ));
         console.log(a.join(','))
         return a.join(',');
     }
     
    return(
        <div>
        {cheangeUpperCase()}
        </div>
    );
}
export default New;
```