# Splitting capital letters with spaces

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, I need a function to split a string based on if it's a capital letter.

Example:

string = "KitKat" should return "Kit Kat".

This is simple to do but, Where I am confused with is when there is a string like "IOTOttawa" I want it to return "IOT Ottawa".

If it has subsequent capitals then keep them together except for the last capital.

Something like that, this is what I have:

```
s = s.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1 $2');
```

I tried using regex but maybe there is another way?

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> [mcve]

Comment: Why regex? Why not a simple `for` loop?

Comment: What about selecting a captial when it's not preceded by a capital?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert space before capital letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582228/insert-space-before-capital-letters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can understand a capital letter if there is a small letter after that.

```
"IOTOttowa".replace(/([A-Z][a-z])/g, ' $1').trim()
```

That code will work for your statement.

Comment: Excellent this worked I also forgot to add that some strings may alos include numbers. For example: 'BellWifi5G' should return 'Bell Wifi 5G'

Comment: @ousmane784 you can use `/([A-Z][a-z]|[0-9][A-Z])/g` for that. 

Also I'll be happy if you vote my answer and accept the solution.