# How to split a string by uppercase and lowercase in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

Is it possible to split Strings in JavaScript by case such that the following string below (myString) would be converted into the array (myArray) below:

```
var myString = "HOWtoDOthis";
var myArray = ["HOW", "to", "DO", "this"];
```

I have tried the regex below, but it only splits for camelCase:

```
.match(/[A-Z]*[^A-Z]+/g);
```

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/7599674/586030

Comment: Give this a try: `/(?:[A-Z]+|[^A-Z]+)/g` https://regex101.com/r/hR3kE3/1

Comment: that worked perfectly, squint - however, I can't set Q as answered as you posted a comment

Comment: Glad it helped. You've got other answers below you can mark.

Comment: duplicate [Javascript Split string on UpperCase Characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888238/javascript-split-string-on-uppercase-characters)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`([A-Z]+|[a-z]+)`. Match all upper case, or all lower case multiple times in capturing groups. Give this a try here: https://regex101.com/r/bC8gO3/1

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do this is to add in a marker and then split using that marker, in this case a double-exclamation point:

[JsBin Example](https://jsbin.com/jolayu/2/edit?js,console)

```
var s = "HOWtoDOthis";

var t = s.replace(/((?:[A-Z]+)|([^A-Z]+))/g, '!!$&').split('!!');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split an CamelCased String following will work

```
/**
 * howToDoThis ===> ["", "how", "To", "Do", "This"]
 * @param word word to be split
 */
export const splitCamelCaseWords = (word: string) => {
    if (typeof word !== 'string') return [];
    return word.replace(/([A-Z]+|[A-Z]?[a-z]+)(?=[A-Z]|\b)/g, '!$&').split('!');
};
```