# Extract "Red" "Blue" "Circle" "Black" from "RedBlueCircleBlack" using capital as delimiter?

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

Is this a RegEx problem?

To note: there will always be only four items, each starts with a capital letter, each will be in order (color,color,shape,color):
"BlackWhiteTriangleGreen" etc.

So,

```
    a="BlackWhiteTriangleGreen"
```

yields:

```
    c1 = "Black"  
    c2 = "White"  
    S = "Triangle"  
    c3 = "Green"
```

EDIT: referencing the post suggested by Alex K., an AS3 solution as follows works:

```
    private function UpperCaseArray(input:String):void {
        var result:String = input.replace(/([A-Z]+)/g, ",$1").replace(/^,/, "");
        var b:Array=result.split(",");
        c1 = b[0];
        c2 = b[1];
        S = b[2];
        c3 = b[3];
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript Split string on UpperCase Characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888238/javascript-split-string-on-uppercase-characters)

Comment: `/([A-Z][a-z]+)/g`

Comment: @AlexK. Thank you! I looked for an answer, but got scared off by "javascript" answer. Didn't realize they were so similar. Is this the reason why someone voted my question down, do you think?

Comment: Its a common question, the downvotes are probably because its expected that you show what you have already attempted.

Comment: @ThePerplexedOne how would one utilize your statement: "/([A-Z][a-z]+)/g"??

Comment: @Chowzen: `input_string.match(/([A-Z][a-z]+)/g)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

referencing the post suggested by Alex K., an AS3 solution as follows works:

```
private function UpperCaseArray(input:String):void {  
    var result:String = input.replace(/([A-Z]+)/g, ",$1").replace(/^,/, "");
    var b:Array=result.split(",");
    c1 = b[0];
    c2 = b[1];
    S = b[2];
    c3 = b[3];
}
```