# Split words on desired regions

Tags: javascript, regex

I encountered a case where I need to split `String` per word that is in camel case. I'm implementing the split process similar to the [answer this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7888303/4043409) using this pattern:

```
split(/(?=[A-Z])/)
```

Everything is fine until I encountered this test set:

- SalaryGrade - Salary Grade
- ParentChild - Parent Child
- Maintenance - Maintenance
- RemittanceSPD - Remittance S P D
- FBIAgent - F B I Agent
- FBIAgentNYDepartment - F B I Agent N Y Department

One up to three works fine, but four to six should be "Remittance SPD",  "FBI Agent", "FBI Agent NY Department" respectively.

How can I select the regions in such a way that it will treat successive upper case letter as one word and the last of the sequence as the start of the next word? I'm not that fond of one-liner Regex to be honest and I'm losing all hope. I'm planning to perform a brute force loop here, if not only about that performance.

EDIT: I want both words with non-succeeding uppercase letters and those with succeeding uppercase letters to be satisfied with this function, unlike the other questions about splitting strings here on this site.

Comment: Too bad JS doesn't support lookbehind, or `/(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])/` would have been enough

Comment: Try `str.match(/[A-Z]+(?![a-z])|[A-Z][a-z]*/g)`

Comment: @Aaron I just tested look-behind too, some minutes ago, and yeah, too bad. That's why I'm thinking of looping it.

Comment: @Wiktor Thanks, would you mind explaining the logic behind it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a *matching* approach here:

```
str.match(/[A-Z]+(?![a-z])|[A-Z][a-z]*/g)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BehMaH/1)

**Details**:

- `[A-Z]+(?![a-z])` - 1+ uppercase ASCII letters NOT followed with a lowercase ASCII letter
- `|` - or
- `[A-Z][a-z]*` - an uppercase ASCII letter followed with 0+ lowercase ASCII letter

```js
var ss = ['SalaryGrade','ParentChild','Maintenance','RemittanceSPD','FBIAgent','FBIAgentNYDepartment'];
var rx = /[A-Z]+(?![a-z])|[A-Z][a-z]*/g; 
for (var s = 0; s < ss.length; s++) { 
  console.log("Testing: ", ss[s], "... ");
  console.log("Matched: ", JSON.stringify(ss[s].match(rx)));
}
```

Note that in case of  `FBIAgent`, the `FBI` are only matched with `[A-Z]+(?![a-z])` due to the backtracking that gets triggered after the regex engine grabs the `FBIA` uppercase letters with `[A-Z]+`: it backtracks to the position where the uppercase is not followed with a lowercase letter, and thus, you get `FBI` match, and the `A` letters remains to be consumed at the next iteration.

Answer (score -1):

The following should help:

```
/(?=[A-Z][a-z])/
```

Comment: Wont work if the uppercases are at the ned, e.g. 'RemittanceSPD'