# How to split a string into substrings using special keywords?

Tags: angular, string, typescript, split, substring

I have to split a string into an array. It has to split when it finds the special substring denoted by '@ + keyword'. Example of keywords:

- @alpha
- @beta
- @lolli

  **Input:**

  'AAHSD@alphaHDHDG@alphaSGTDHDGT@betaSDGSDFHDG@alphaASFAGF@lolliSFDSFG@alphaSGHSHSF@lolliGA'

  **Desired Output**

  [A,A,H,S,D, @alpha, H,D,H,D,G, @alpha, S,G,T,D,H,D,G,T, @beta, S,D,G,S,D,F,H,D,G, @alpha, 
  A,S,F,A,G,F, @lolli, S,F,D,S,F,G, @alpha, S,G,H,S,H,S,F, @lolli, G,A]

Comment: There are [hundreds of string splitting questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Btypescript%5D+split+string) already, what have you tried?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888238/javascript-split-string-on-uppercase-characters please refer this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a good task for using regular expressions.

In your case regular expression will look like: `@(alpha|beta|loli)`

https://regex101.com/r/Rfx0ih/2

You can iterate over match collection and use match indexes to cut required strings.

or just use:

```
'AAHSD@alphaHDHDG@alphaSGTDHDGT@betaSDGSDFHDG@alphaASFAGF@lolliSFDSFG@alphaSGHSHSF@lolliGA'.split(/@(alpha|beta|lolli)/)
```

Comment: what if there are more then three keywords ? then you would have to add them manually.

Comment: It should be OK up to few hundreds. I don't get "you would have to add them manually" - as a developer if you need to add something you do. There are different ways how you keep information and what algoritms you use but source data is source data and either harcoded or loaded from somewhere. It's up to developer to decide what works best in his/here case.

Comment: yes, it is one of the solutions but not an efficient one. Please check my answer to get more idea. It will cover all the keywords

Comment: You can't judge solution without defining requirements and input data. For now you don't know for sure if in between there is low case data. And you solution is not complete as it returns "D@alpha" for example that need to be cleaned additionally.

Comment: @AlexanderTrakhimenok This sounds good to me. It's true I will need to add them manually, but for now it's okay. When I see them increase, I will take time to think to something more scalable. I will try it out and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple 
You can split it from the Capital letters to get desired outcome like follows:-

```
'AAHSD@alphaHDHDG@alphaSGTDHDGT@betaSDGSDFHDG@alphaASFAGF@lolliSFDSFG@alphaSGHSHSF@lolliGA'.split(/(?=[A-Z])/);
```

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't specify properly, there could be lower case letters as well.