# Regex: prevent splitting subsequent uppercase letters

Tags: javascript, regex

I am splitting a string into words for any uppercase letter and I am using the following regex:

```
'ThisIsTheStringToSplit'.match(/[A-Z][a-z]+/g);
```

[Javascript Split string on UpperCase Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888238/javascript-split-string-on-uppercase-characters)

However if there are two or more upper case letters in a row I only want to split from the first letter.

`'THISIsTheStringToSplit'` would split into the words `THISIs`, `The`, `String`, `To`, `Split`.

How can I use regex to handle this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go:

```
var str = "THISIsTheStringToSplit".match(/[A-Z]+[a-z]*/g);
```

This will return an array with all the matches as required.

Also, this will handle the case where all alphabets are capital.

Example:

```
var str = "THISI".match(/[A-Z]+[a-z]*/g);
```

This will return THISI

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following, written as per shown samples.

```
.match(/[A-Z]+[a-z]+/g);
```

It will simply match one or more occurrences of capital alphabets followed by 1 or more occurrences of small letters.