# How to split strings into an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to split strings into an array in javascript?
I tried this below

```
const Vehicles = "Sedan" + "Coupe" + "Minivan"
  const Output = Vehicles.split(",")

   console.log(Output)
```

and the results was

```
["SedanCoupeMinivan",]
```

However I would like the results to instead be this below

```
["Sedan", "Coupe", "Minivan"]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript Split string on UpperCase Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888238/javascript-split-string-on-uppercase-characters)

Comment: To get what you want, you need to include the delimiter ","

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original string

```
const Vehicles = "Sedan" + "Coupe" + "Minivan"
```

results in `"SedanCoupeMinivan"` as the value of `Vehicles`.

Then you try to split that by a comma:

```
const Output = Vehicles.split(",")
```

As the orignal string that you tried to split does not contain a single comma, the result you got is quite what I would expect.

You could assemble the original string with commas:

```
const Vehicles = "Sedan" + "," + "Coupe" + "," + "Minivan"
```

and the split should work as you expected.

Answer (score 2):

Well there are 2 methods to this, either changing the string and adding commas or using match function.

Method 1:

```
const Vehicles = "Sedan," + "Coupe," + "Minivan"
const Output = Vehicles.split(",")

console.log(Output)
```

Method 2:

```
const Vehicles = "Sedan" + "Coupe" + "Minivan"
const Output = Vehicles.match(/[A-Z][a-z]+/g);

console.log(Output)
```

Both work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `Vehicles` is just **ONE** long string. You combined the three strings and made them one. You cannot go back. Unless you use `substring` (for example) to cut the string wherever you want...

If you want to split the string at a specific character, like `,` you need to make sure the string has `,` between each part you want to cut.