# JS: Using split or regex to manipulate a string

Tags: javascript

I am trying to always convert a string based on the first 2 capitalized letters and then hyphenate those 2 words and ignore everything after.

so `SourceSansPro-ExtraLight` would be `source-sans`

I was able to use `split` to remove the hyphen and then ignore everything after it can't account for the other part, which is just paying attention to the first 2 capitalized words.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript Split string on UpperCase Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888238/javascript-split-string-on-uppercase-characters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it with regex.

```js
const str = 'SourceSansPro-ExtraLight';
const match = str.replace(/([A-Z][a-z]+)([A-Z][a-z]+).*/, '$1-$2');
console.log(match);
```