# Why does map() turn every item of the array into undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, dictionary

```
function splitCamelCase(string) {
  return string.split(/([A-Z])/g)
  .map(function(x,i) {
    if (x === x.toUpperCase()) {
      x[i+1] = x + x[i+1]
      x = " "
      
    }
    
  })
.join('')
}
```

This code is supposed to split camel case text at each uppercase letter, but it just turns every item of the array to undefined
As far as I understand nothing here is changing the values to something they shouldnt be

Tried changing "x[i+1] = x + x[i+1]" to " = `${x}${x[i+1]}`, nothing happened
Tried specifying the array in the map function parameters, notthing changed

Comment: Your `.map()` callback function doesn't return anything. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#parameters

Comment: where is the return?

Comment: Functions in javascript returns `undefined` when you don't return anything. While other languages like Java and C++ have the `void` type for functions that don't return anything in javascript "nothingness" actually have a value and it's `undefined`

Comment: also [When should I use a return statement in ES6 arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889450/when-should-i-use-a-return-statement-in-es6-arrow-functions) if you choose to use an arrow function instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you've got is you're not returning anything in the map.

That said, there's a simpler way to achieve the result you're after:

```
function splitCamelCase(string) {
   return string.split(/(?=[A-Z])/).join(" ");
}
```

[Javascript Split string on UpperCase Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888238/javascript-split-string-on-uppercase-characters)