# How can I format a camel cased key name to have spaces using a handlebars helper?

Tags: javascript, templates, handlebars.js

```
{{#each data}}
    <div>
        {{@key}} : {{this}}
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

Heres what the data structure looks like:

```
data: {
    maxHealth: Number,
    maxMana: Number,
    chanceToCrit: Number,
},
```

I have something set up similarly to this and it is displaying the key name and the value as I want. However, the key is displaying in camel case, such as: maxHealth, maxMana, etc.

Id like the keys to display as: max health, max mana, chance to crit, in this instance, but I wont know the key names and values ahead of time, they will be random each time. How can I use a handlebar helper to format the key for me?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Show where the data is coming from

Comment: added data structure.

Comment: So you want something like `max Health` instead of  `maxHealth`

Comment: yes thats it exactly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out how to [create a helper in Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html).

The idiomatic way to (-slaps knee-) *handle* this is registering a helper, like this one:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('uncamelcase', function(str) {
    return doTheUncamelCasing(str);
});
```

Where `doTheUncamelCasing` is some function you create to transform the string from `camelCaseStyle` to `camel case style`. Then, use your new helper in the template:

```
{{uncamelcase @key}}
```

Comment: hi thanks for the response. How can I go about formatting it to have spaces though?

Comment: You can google the keywords "CamelCase" and "Sentence case" : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4149276/javascript-camelcase-to-regular-form